# How to fix "more than one foreign key" Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django (using version: 2.1.5)(Python 3.6) and trying to mess around with some models. I am building a chess database. This relies on 3 models, the players, the game and the moves comprising the game. For each game there is a white player and a black player, both of the class player. This raises an error:

```
<'class 'chessengine.admin.GameInline'>: (admin.E202) 'chessengine.Game' has more than one ForeignKey to 'chessengine.Player'.
```

I tried using reference names which removed an earlier related error but will not deal with the one above.

```
//models.py


class Player(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birth_date = models.DateField('birthday')

    def game_count(self):
        return Player.objects.filter(Games__white_player=self.name).count() + Player.objects.filter(Games__black_player=self.name).count()


class Game(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField('date played')
    moves = models.IntegerField()
    white_player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='white_player')
    black_player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='black_player')
    result = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

```
//admin.py

class GameInline(admin.TabularInline):

    inlines = [MoveInline]
    model = Game


class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Player Information',               {'fields': ['name', 'birth_date']}),
        ('Game Information', {'fields': ['date', 'player_white', 'player_black', 'result'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [GameInline]
    list_display = ('name', 'birth_date', 'game_count')
    list_filter = ['name']
```

Comment: You need to rethink your model

Comment: Looks like the `related_name`s are the *same* here, in contrast with tis code fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Game model` has multiple ForeignKey to `Player model`. So while defining `TabularInline for Game ie. GameInline` you have to add `fk_name` to `GameInline`

```
class GameInline(admin.TabularInline):
    inlines = [MoveInline]
    model = Game
    fk_name = 'white_player`
```

Read more about fk_name [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Was about to complain that it was missing from the docs, but there it is!

Comment: @Nic I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two references to the Player Table in that fashion.  What you should to is have a `type` for player (and make use of the choice fields possibly) that will be either `white` or `black`:

```
class Player(models.Model):

    PLAYER_TYPES = (("W", "White"), ("B", "Black")

    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, null=False, choices=PLAYER_TYPES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birth_date = models.DateField('birthday')

def game_count(self):
    return Player.objects.filter(Games__white_player=self.name).count() + Player.objects.filter(Games__black_player=self.name).count()


class Game(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField('date played')
    moves = models.IntegerField()
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player')
    result = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

EDIT:  It appears you *can* have two references to the player table, but I would likely still implement a choice or similar solution..